# how to restrict access to heroku app (standard-domain)?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, gunicorn

I am new to heroku and experimenting with python plotly dash and gunicorn like described in this article: https://dash.plotly.com/deployment (see heroku-part of the docu).

The running app is accessible via the domain: https://some-example-name.herokuapp.com/ . I wonder if there is a way to restrict this access. I didn't find anything about this in the heroku docu.